# Coalesce throwing error even though it should suppress

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?resource ?date ?dateFixed
WHERE { 
      ?resource a dbo:Royalty ; 
      foaf:depiction ?depiction ; 
      dbo:birthDate ?date ; 
      dbo:birthPlace ?bp . 
      bind(coalesce(xsd:dateTime(?date), '3000-01-01'^^xsd:dateTime) as ?dateFixed) . 
}
```

When I try the query I get `Virtuoso 22007 Error DT006: Cannot convert 1693-0-0 to datetime : Incorrect month value`. Shouldn't Coalesce suppress that error?

Comment: It's a known issue in the DBpedia dataset that many date literals do have an illegal syntax. The error message shows just one of them

Comment: you can use a REGEX FILTER on the date to avoid this error. for example, `filter(regex(str(?date),'[0-2]{1}[0-9]{3}-[0,1]{1}[0-9]{1}-[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}'))` - (indeed the pattern isn't perfect for valid dates in general, but at least it covers `yyyy-mm-dd`)

Comment: But shouldn't coalesce suppress the error either way even if `xsd:dateTime(?date)` gets an invalid `?date`?

Comment: The first value without an error, sure -  I'm not a Virtuoso dev but maybe something is wrong internally. You should open a Github issue. Anyways, the regex workaround should work

Comment: I tried your regex, but when I then try to compare the date I still get the same error: `filter(regex(str(?bd),'[0-2]{1}[0-9]{3}-[0,1]{1}[0-9]{1}-[0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}')) . filter(xsd:dateTime(?bd) < xsd:dateTime('1900-01-01')) . `

Comment: well, now you are using an additional filter...that wasn't shown in your initial query. Clearly, it looks like this filter is evaluated first, that's why the error still occurs. To be honest, I don't understand why you convert to `xsd:dateTime` first and then do the comparison. Why are you not comparing the `xsd:date` literals?

Comment: I read somewhere that you should use xsd:dateTime for comparisons. I just noticed that when I use xsd:date the coalesce colution works fine BUT the date values change. `bind(coalesce(xsd:date(?date), xsd:date('3000-01-01')) as ?dateFixed) . filter(xsd:date(?dateFixed) < xsd:date('1900-01-01')) . ` I don't know what's happening anymore.

I just want to get the date and check if it's <1900-01-01. If I just check for xsd:date everything works fine, but I noticed that I miss a lot of results because some objects only have the date formatted as a string. So I tried to parse the string.

Comment: for example, which date is missed of you use `xsd:date`? you can filter by datatype if necessary. And you have another problem, some people might have multiple dates in the dataset. For example, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anne,_Queen_of_Great_Britain

Comment: I found when I do the comparison inline, it seems to work. The one in my comment above would have different values for `?date` and `?dateFixed`. The only explanation I have is, that `?dateFixed` prevails between resources and a resource might get assigned a `?dateFixed` from a fixed one if the parsing failed.